# Create a Patch without 2nd MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch

I believe Patch works by creating a transform by comparing the existing MSI (1st one) and the new one (2nd MSI). I have a customer requirement (don't ask me why) not to create the 2nd MSI and still have another option to create a patch. Is this possible? If so, can you please provide the details? If not, can you please provide links / proofs substantiating this?

Comment: You mean [create a MSP file](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html)?

Comment: Yes. I mean create an MSP file without a second MSI.

Comment: Why does the customer care if you create an updated MSI file then use it to create the patch and then give them the patch? They never see the 2nd MSI, just that patch. Building the patch is your internal dev process and nothing to do with "requirements".

Answer (score 1):

Since all files are just a collection of bytes, it's hard to prove the impossibility. However the only Microsoft-documented way to create a patch (.msp file) involves invoking [patchwiz.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370590) (perhaps through msimsp.exe) to process the differences between two or more installation databases (.msi files). [Creating a Patch Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368060) describes this process in more detail.

If you got past this, skipping msimsp.exe/patchwiz.dll and thus avoiding creating the upgraded .msi file here, you would still have to create the transforms that go in the [transform substorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370596#transform_substorage). The only documented way to [generate a transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368620) (.mst file) still requires two installation databases, so you'd need your second .msi file for this step.

If you figure out how to generate .mst files without a pair of .msi files, then in theory it may also be possible to package it all up into a .msp file. I have yet to see enough documentation on how to do this, however.

<sup>(Pointers to that documentation would be gratefully accepted, whether as comments, edits, or alternate answers.)</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've created an MSI but opening an MSI database, making changes to it in memory and then generating the MST. This is what ORCA does.  I suspect Ven might want to look at InstallShield's QuickPatch project type.

Comment: Sure, but I think all those scenarios create a second .msi file of some sort. Though they may be temporary, and deleted before you have to think about it. Base concept is that the proposed requirement makes no sense to me. You don't need to distribute it, but the .msi file still has to be made.

Comment: A patch is just a delivery mechanism for an upgrade that is already working - I know I read this statement when first looking at patching years ago. I was very surprised at this fact back then. Given this fact, it must be impossible to generate a patch without two MSI files to compare? Like Michael says, there must be at least a temporary MSI file generated.